# Does turtlebot works on Kubuntu?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to install Turtlebot on a netbook that uses Kubuntu 10.04.
But i couldn't find the Meta Package for turtlebot-robot via Synaptic neither by apt-cache search...

Is possible to run turtlebot on Kubuntu? And how can I to install it?

Thanks,

Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11066/does-turtlebot-works-on-kubuntu?/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most everything should work on Kubuntu as on Ubuntu. Just follow the [Ubuntu instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/SDK%20Setup/Ubuntu%20Deb)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4